# How To Create A Two-Step Form That Can Submit If User Doesn't Complete Step Two?

Tags: php, forms, email

I'd like to create a two step email signup form, which will submit to Aweber (or any company where this isn't a standard feature).

The idea is to first ask for the minimum info necessary - name, email - and then on step two, attempt to get additional info for segmenting the list. For example, *Do you like dairy or meat better?*.

The challenge is that if the user doesn't complete step two, I'd still like to add them to the email list with just their partial data... but I might not have a user action (ex.: a button click) at this point, with which to trigger a form submission.

How would you solve this? I figure AJAX is part of the solution, but as I'm still learning PHP, a PHP solution would be preferable. (I'm basically ignorant of JavaScript/AJAX except for their existence.)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to submit the first step (required data; presumably with AJAX, but not necessarily) and save to database.  If/when step 2 is completed, you would update database with additional data.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that! I had thought to do something like that, but where I get stuck is that I don't know how I would submit the data (other than manually) . I'm just familiar with using a form submission to enter info into the db.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to do a submit if the user *doesn't* do something, which is not in itself a trappable event! However, there is a solution. (Note I don't know what "Aweber" is, but I'll assume you must send all your data to that, via an API, in one shot).

Start off with creating the first form, and have it save to the database with a timestamp. Don't submit anything externally yet - just redirect to the second step, and if the second step is completed, save the second block of information to your local database, and then submit everything to the API (you'll need to retrieve the first block of data from your database, of course).

Now, you'll start building up a set of records for which the second step is incomplete. To submit these, run a scheduler (such as `cron`) to detect any records that are unsubmitted after 10 minutes (or whatever time you believe a second step to be abandoned). For each such record, submit it with just the first block of data to the API, then mark it as sent, so very sluggish users cannot then complete the second step. If you think it appropriate, you'll have to explicitly prevent late submission in your second form (since there is no point in accepting the data if you can no longer submit it remotely).

You'll notice that AJAX is not part of this proposal, and I'm not sure I'd recommend it. That would only work using a timer event on the second page, but if the user closes the second page before the timer fires, your event will never trigger, and the user's data will not be submitted.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer and the one above answer my question adequately. Basically I need to learn how to use their API or how to use AJAX to solve this issue. Appreciate your time and help!

Comment: @gabrielg: pleased it was of use! In case you don't know, it's worth accepting/upvoting helpful answers - it's how we 'reward' effort here, even if the currency is rather virtual `:)`.

Comment: I tried to but you need 15 rep points n I don't have that much yet. :) I am grateful, please don't think otherwise.

Comment: @gabrielg: Ah, I keep forgetting, apologies! No worries, it's cool.